# Линукс завис на бесконечной загрузке

Tags: linux, grub

Я ввела эти команды в терминал линукса:

```bash
sudo groupadd pcap
sudo usermod -a -G pcap $USER
sudo chgrp pcap /usr/bin/tcpdump
```

У него пропали все иконки и картинки, потом я его выключила, а включить не смогла.

Он может перейти в рекавери режим.
Там я пробовала grub и dpkg, потом нажимаю resume и перехожу на экран tty1.

На нем запрашивается логин и пароль, я их ввожу, но они продолжают запрашиваться снова.

Что делать? Как включить ноутбук?

При выборе fsck пишет: cannot continue, aborting.

Comment: При выборе fsck пишет cannot continue, aborting

Comment: В такой не понятной ситуации, если есть важные данные, да и на всякий случай нужно сделать копию диска. Потом уже с загрузочной флешки можно fsck запустить. **fsck пишет: cannot continue, aborting.** возможно, но точно не видно, из-за того что файловая система примонтирована, а примонтированную не рекомендуется лечить.

Comment: Ну так если в рекавери можешь зайти - удали своего юзера из группы `pcap`. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29572

Answer (score 0):

В tty пароля может и не быть. Попробуйте жать Enter